# Why are two birds obsessed with a chopped-down tree?

Tags: birds, trees, bird-behaviour

Where I work, there was a great pine tree which was recently chopped (actually, sawed) down.

Prior to its demise, this tall pine was visited often by lizards and birds.

After its removal, though, the remaining stump has seemed to hold a fascination for a pair of dark birds, and I'm stumped (no pun intended) as to why. I don't know what kind they are. They're not juncos, but are about the same size.

They are not actively seeking bugs or such - they simply stand on the stump looking around and at each other, sometimes walking around on it.

Is it because this was their tree, and they are confused? They still feel an attraction to it? They had a nest in it?

This is in Santa Cruz, on the central California Coast.

Comment: If you came home and your house was gone, just the foundation was left, you'd probably act the same way.

Comment: Hi B. Clay Shannon! I know it's been years since you wrote this, but I'm curious as to what happened. Did those birds just do that for a short time and leave? Did they return at another time, for instance in a subsequent year, which could potentially mean looking for the same nesting spot? It's interesting that they weren't eating from that stump. There are lots of bird-goodies in there! If you're not around or don't feel like answering this, that's fine!

Comment: I wasn't there much longer, so I don't know what happened with that tree and the local birds. I still live in Crow City, though (Monterey, California). And I'm still curious what it is about Monterey that makes crows love it so much/thrive there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This usually means that they had a nest in the tree. If they are still there after a few days it probably means they also had young. Either still in the nest or young enough that they still returned to be fed.